# Remove partial matches from list in sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter

I'm trying to compare two arrays and remove any matches(Partial). This seems like it should be simple but I can't wrap my head around it.

[image: Remove matches]

The sheet is found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_jPJOST-8DbpTwVcoFGXFzdpo-1bXSMnwJcgEMnNk3U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the premise on that but used textjoin to make sure I could add more rows. Thanks!

=FILTER(A2:A,NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,textJOIN("|",TRUE, B2:B))))

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=FILTER(A2:A5,NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A5,JOIN("|",B2:B3))))
```

[image]